# Spring + AngularJS (HTML) getting Context Path?

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, jsp

I am currently using Spring and AngularJS.

So far no problem displaying my `index.html` using Spring like so

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String index() {
    return "/app/index.html";
}
```

Is there any way I can get my context path in my `.html`? Or should I render my `index` as `index.jsp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, you should render it as a JSP in order to access the contextpath:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

If you wanna stick to pure HTML maybe you could extract it from the URL with Javascript:

```
function getContextPath() {
    return window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
}
console.log(getContextPath());
```

Comment: Yeah I'm hoping for other options though if they exist.

Comment: The JS alternative will do for now. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an easy way to append the result of getContextPath() to a href link?